# Restrict Azure Application access to a specific folder in OneDrive

Tags: python, django, azure, onedrive, azure-api-apps

We have a requirement to upload to and read files from a single folder in OneDrive for Business through a Django app. We are using Microsoft Graph API with application permission. While the Azure provides `Files.ReadWrite.All` permission, the application can also potentially access all files and folders, as provided in graph permissions reference:

```
Allows the app to read all files in all site collections without a signed in user.
```

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference)

Is there a way to use Graph API's Application `Files.ReadWrite.All` Permission while restricting the application's access to a single folder in OneDrive?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, - You will not be able to achieve your requirement of restricting the Application Permission to a file level using app only permissions.

**Other suggestion**

- You could create a service account with a minimal permission -
  restricting the access to only specific folder.
- You can do a use delegate app permission and access files for which
  this account has access.
- If you are looking for a non-interactive way to get a token
  You could ROPC method of authentication
  The credential for the service accounts is passed along - there is no interaction required to acquire token.

**Reference :**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Comment: @Ayush - Did  the above answser help or do you have any queries ?

Comment: Hi @Satya. Thanks for your prompt reply. I used ROPC method as you suggested and it works great! However for some reason, Microsoft suggests to use alternatives to the ROPC flow because it's not as secure.